# how to display data using RecyclerView in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, mysql, database, android-recyclerview

I want to display data using a RecyclerView. but has a problem: `"java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.setLayoutManager(androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager)' on a null object reference"`

and this exception

```
"java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.setLayoutManager(androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager)' on a null object reference"
(ViewActivity.java:45)
```

this code

```
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_view);

    ButterKnife.bind(this);
    viewAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(this, perusahaan);
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    recyclerView.setAdapter(viewAdapter);

    LoadDataPerusahaan();
}
```

Comment: Is this `ViewActivity.java` resides in app module or have you created a new library module and this activity is part of that module? Please post the complete file.

Comment: load the data first and then invoke the adapter

Comment: initialize the RecyclerView first of all

Comment: Hi, you are using the ButterKnife library to bind the views in your XML code. Show us and view the binding code or double-check the recyclerView id again.

Comment: did your Butterknife declaration match your xml declaration

Answer (score 0):

This problem is for initialize `recyclerview`,
you can check `ButterKnife` again to be sure work correctly.